Making FastAPI ML server faster
I have a FastAPI server where upon a HTTP GET (/get_documents/), there are 2 bottlenecks to returning a response fast: there is a call to another server via a client ("get vectors"), then there is a call to an LLM (in process memory) to generate text. Both are very slow. I'm thinking that the "get vectors" call to the other server could be put behind an await, so that the CPU is freed while waiting for the external call to come back. However, I don't think the call to the LLM in process would benefit from being behind an await, since it does require to complete on the CPU to answer the query. Further, I am not sure if I should make the /get_documents/ async for FastAPI. I keep reading about this, but get lost since there is talk of "threads" but python has the GIL... What would be the best strategy for the external call (via client) and the call to the LLM, as well as that /get_documents/ that runs in FastAPI? I'm hoping for a very simple solution, if possible.

This might prove helpful as well, if you are calling some external API.

@Chris That other answer, which I had already seen, is really hard to parse for me. There are many alternatives and I get lost in the details.

You might want to create a reusable ProcessPool, similar to this answer, and access it within endpoints using request.state.pool. You might also want to have a look at other tools, such as Celery, and/or increase the number of workers of your app. It is all explained in the link above.

It should be quick to test - just drop the async keyword on your function and starlette will run it in a threadpool automagically - so that you can see whether the GIL would affect it. The GIL does not make threads unusable in Python, so you will probably be just fine, depending on your usage. You can also consider using the subprocess module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html or other task queues that allow you to run the heavy part in a completely separate application.
